# If an object value exists in an array of objects then return entire object

Tags: javascript

I have one array and one object:

```
const currentData = [{first: 'Breanna', last: 'Bazadoo', uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},
{first: 'Foo', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'},
{first: 'Foo2', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE'},
{first: 'Foo3', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX'}
];

const ministryMembers = { -MmFNu4jQ8A4_Aig0vdn: "-MmFNu4jQ8A4_Aig0vdn",
-Mxg8xKwZleW4J8yfzna: "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO",
-Mxg9AxhUR6ZArBATw1M: "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE",
-Mxg9ECyBsj01zMqPE8s: "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU",
-Mxg9GvmPFabK_185IOr: "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH",
-Mxg9JbJ2sxgWLxk1tfx: "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3",
-Mxg9MZTKzlUD0lg07C0: "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX",
-Mxg9Pnfmv7P3BQvINQV: "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT",
-Mxg9SB2vlOopJYtmG-Z: "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4",
-Mxg9VrZFDNawvcWIgul: "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1" }
```

if currentData's uid is found in allMembers value
in example currentData uid == allMembers value,
I want to return the entire object from currentData and build the array again.  There will be a lot more in currentData this is just an example.

I have done this:

```
const filteredData = Object.keys(ministryMembers).filter( m => currentData.find( cd => cd.uid == ministryMembers[m] ) );
console.log(filteredData);
```

It returns only the key.  How can I get it to return the whole object?
My other option was map the data and then return the whole object that way but I thought that there might be a more efficent way of doing it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: in object `allMembers`, is `uid` `key` or `value` ?  and what is `ministryMembers` ?

Comment: value and sorry I fixed it allMembers was supposed to be ministryMembers

Comment: what is expect data for you !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work?

```
var valueList = Object.values(ministryMembers);
var filteredData = currentData.filter(e => valueList.includes(e.uid));
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03bpak9m/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
currentData.filter(e => typeof allMembers[e.uid] !== 'undefined')
```

or

```
currentData.filter(e => allMembers.hasOwnProperty(e.uid))
```

Comment: Only returns one allMembers should be ministryMembers which is an ojject.  e.uid should be the value of allMembers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If there is large data then you can process it in chunks.

```js
var filteredArray = [];
function processData(data, allMembers) {
  // process data in chunks -> 100 at a time
  let chunks = data.splice(0, 100);
  chunks.forEach((element) => {
    if (Object.keys(allMembers).find((e) => allMembers[e] === element.uid)) {
      filteredArray.push(element);
    }
  });
  if (data.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      processData(data,allMembers);
    }, 0);
  } else {
    // processing complete
    console.log(filteredArray);
  }
}

var currentData = [{first: 'Breanna', last: 'Bazadoo', uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},
{first: 'Foo', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'},
{first: 'Foo2', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE'},
{first: 'Foo3', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX'}
];

var ministryMembers = { "-MmFNu4jQ8A4_Aig0vdn": "-MmFNu4jQ8A4_Aig0vdn",
"-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO",
"-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE",
"-Mxg9ECyBsj01zMqPE8s": "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU",
"-Mxg9GvmPFabK_185IOr": "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH",
"-Mxg9JbJ2sxgWLxk1tfx": "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3",
"-Mxg9MZTKzlUD0lg07C0": "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX",
"-Mxg9Pnfmv7P3BQvINQV": "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT",
"-Mxg9SB2vlOopJYtmG-Z": "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4",
"-Mxg9VrZFDNawvcWIgul": "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1" };

processData(currentData,ministryMembers);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(ministryMembers)` return an array of keys

`Object.keys(ministryMembers).filter(...)` filter in above array

What is expect result for you !??

If you want data from `currentData` try it :

```js
const currentData = [
  {first: 'Breanna', last: 'Bazadoo', uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},
  {first: 'Foo', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'},
  {first: 'Foo2', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE'},
  {first: 'Foo3', last: 'Bazado', uid: '-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX'}
]

const ministryMembers = { 
  '-MmFNu4jQ8A4_Aig0vdn': "-MmFNu4jQ8A4_Aig0vdn",
  '-Mxg8xKwZleW4J8yfzna': "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO",
  '-Mxg9AxhUR6ZArBATw1M': "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE",
  '-Mxg9ECyBsj01zMqPE8s': "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU",
  '-Mxg9GvmPFabK_185IOr': "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH",
  '-Mxg9JbJ2sxgWLxk1tfx': "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3",
  '-Mxg9MZTKzlUD0lg07C0': "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX",
  '-Mxg9Pnfmv7P3BQvINQV': "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT",
  '-Mxg9SB2vlOopJYtmG-Z': "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4",
  '-Mxg9VrZFDNawvcWIgul': "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1" 
}
// two ways for it
const filteredData = Object.entries(ministryMembers).reduce((res, [key, value]) => {
  let currData = currentData.find(ele => ele.uid === value)
  return typeof currData == 'undefined' ? res : [...res, currData]
}, [])
console.log(filteredData)

const filteredData1 = currentData.filter( m => Object.entries(ministryMembers).some(([key, value]) => value == m.uid ))
console.log(filteredData1)

const filteredData2 = currentData.filter(e => Object.values(ministryMembers).includes(e.uid));
console.log(filteredData2)
```